# Execute remote SSH command and evaluate this command on remote side

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Let's consider a following code:

```
CMD=echo $(hostname --fqdn) >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn
ssh some_user@10.9.11.4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $CMD
```

And now, on remote side created file `/tmp/hostname_fqdn` contains hostname of client side instead of hostname of remote side.  Is it possible to evaluate part of command (`hostname --fqdn)` on remote side?   How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh some_user@10.9.11.4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa hostname --fqdn >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn
```

or, if the `CMD` may change at runtime:

```
CMD="hostname --fqdn" && ssh cloud.luminrobotics.com $CMD >> /tmp/xxx
```

You cannot, however, keep the redirection of the output (`>> filename`) be part of the command variable, because the command will be executed on the remote host.

---

PS: If what you want to do with the output changes at runtime as well, then you need to use a pipe and a separate command variable, e.g.,:

```sh
CMD_REMOTE="hostname --fqdn"
CMD_LOCAL="tee /tmp/hostname_fqdn"
ssh cloud.luminrobotics.com $CMD | $CMD_LOCAL
```

Comment: However, is there exists more general approach? I mean evaluate parts of bash command after ssh ?

Comment: I've added some more to the answer. Maybe that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
CMD=echo $(hostname --fqdn) >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn
```

will likely do nothing like what you expect.

`CMD=echo` will be pasred as setting `echo` as the value of `$CMD`, and then the return from the `hostname` subshell we be executed, and likely fail, creating an empty file `/tmp/hostname_fqdn`

`ssh` on the other hand is pretty flexible. You could use

```
ssh some_user@10.9.11.4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa 'hostname --fqdn >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn'
```

if you want the remote hostname saved to a file on the remote host, or

```
ssh some_user@10.9.11.4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa 'hostname --fqdn' >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn
```

if you want the remote hostname on the local server, or

```
hostname --fqdn | ssh some_user@10.9.11.4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa 'cat >> /tmp/hostname_fqdn'
```

if you want the local hostname on the remote server...

You have options. :)